# How to test class that uses Event sObjects

Tags: apex, account, sobject, event

I'm trying to write a unit test for a class that uses Event sObjects and I don't know how to create an Event variable and assign it an AccountId. Whenever I try to set the AccountId manually I get an error `Field is not writable: Event.AccountId`

Here is the code for the class I'm trying to test:

```
trigger EventAppointmentKept on Event (after update) {
    VisitMeetingCountHandler handler = new VisitMeetingCountHandler();
    Set<id> acctVisitids = new set<id>();
    Set<id> acctMeetingids = new set<id>();
    List<Account> acctWithVisit = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> acctWithMeeting = new List<Account>();

    for (Event e : Trigger.new) {
        Event oldE = Trigger.oldMap.get(e.Id);

        if (!oldE.Appointment_Kept__c && e.Appointment_Kept__c) {
            if (e.Subject.containsIgnoreCase('Meeting')) {
                acctVisitids.add(e.AccountId);
            }
            if (Pattern.matches('PQ Meeting|Signing Meeting|Rewrite Meeting|Online PQ Appointment', e.Subject)) { 
                acctMeetingids.add(e.AccountId);
            } 
        }
    }

    acctWithVisit = [SELECT id, Visit_Count_Current__c FROM Account WHERE id IN: acctVisitids];
    acctWithMeeting = [SELECT id, PQ_Meeting_Count_Current__c FROM Account WHERE id IN: acctMeetingids];

    if (!acctWithVisit.isEmpty()) {
        handler.increaseVisitCountCurrent(acctWithVisit);
    }
    if (!acctWithMeeting.isEmpty()) {
        handler.increasePQCountCurrent(acctWithMeeting);
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@isTest
public class testEventAppointmentKept {
    @isTest static void testEventAppointmentKept() {
        VisitMeetingCountHandler handler = new VisitMeetingCountHandler();
        Set<id> acctVisitids = new set<id>();
        Set<id> acctMeetingids = new set<id>();
        List<Account> acctWithVisit = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> acctWithMeeting = new List<Account>();

        Account testAccount1 = new Account(Name = 'TaskMeetingCompleteUnitTest', first_name__c = 'test', last_name__c = 'test', email__c = 'test@test.com');
        Account testAccount2 = new Account(Name = 'TaskMeetingCompleteUnitTest', first_name__c = 'test test', last_name__c = 'test test', email__c = 'testtest@test.com');

        insert testAccount1;
        insert testAccount2;

        List<Account> accountList = [Select Id From Account Where Name = 'TaskMeetingCompleteUnitTest' limit 2];

        Event noAppointmentKept = new Event(Appointment_Kept__c = false, whoId = testAccount1.id);
        Event appointmentKept = new Event(Appointment_Kept__c = true, subject = 'Meeting', whoId = testAccount2.id);

        List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();

        eventList.add(noAppointmentKept);
        eventList.add(appointmentKept);

        for (Integer i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
            Event e = eventList.get(i);
            Event oldE = eventList.get(0);

            if (!oldE.Appointment_Kept__c && e.Appointment_Kept__c) {
                if (e.Subject.containsIgnoreCase('Meeting')) {
                    acctVisitids.add(e.AccountId);
                }
                if (Pattern.matches('PQ Meeting|Signing Meeting|Rewrite Meeting|Online PQ Appointment', e.Subject)) { 
                    acctMeetingids.add(e.AccountId);
                } 
            }
        }

        acctWithVisit = [SELECT id, Visit_Count_Current__c FROM Account WHERE id IN: acctVisitids];
        acctWithMeeting = [SELECT id, PQ_Meeting_Count_Current__c FROM Account WHERE id IN: acctMeetingids];

        if (!acctWithVisit.isEmpty()) {
            handler.increaseVisitCountCurrent(acctWithVisit);
        }
        if (!acctWithMeeting.isEmpty()) {
            handler.increasePQCountCurrent(acctWithMeeting);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Right now I have 0% code coverage.

Comment: In order to test a trigger, you need to use DML statements. You do not literally copy the trigger code into the test method in order to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should **use WhatId instead of WhoId** while setting AccountId as WhoId is used only to assign ContactId and LeadId.
use the below code to create Event record in test class.

```
Event noAppointmentKept = new Event(Appointment_Kept__c = false, WhatId = testAccount1.id);

Event appointmentKept = new Event(Appointment_Kept__c = true, subject = 'Meeting',WhatId = testAccount2.id);
```

and i think there are missing fields as i run  your code in anonymous window, it asked me for missing fields and the below line of code works fine for me :

```
Account testAccount1 = new Account(Name = 'TaskMeetingCompleteUnitTest');
insert testAccount1;

Event noAppointmentKept = new Event(ActivityDateTime=date.valueOf('2017-08-08'),DurationInMinutes=50, WhatId = testAccount1.id);

insert noAppointmentkept;
```